# How to use 'mex' in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm trying to run this code:

```
mex -O fconv.cc
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Error using mex.  no supported compiler or SDK was found. (link to
>   mathworks sdks, installed the SDK, didn't help).

I't my first use of Matlab. and I can't anything helpful in the internet.

fconv.cc:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

struct thread_data {
  double *A;
  double *B;
  double *C;
  mxArray *mxC;
  const mwSize *A_dims;
  const mwSize *B_dims;
  mwSize C_dims[2];
};

// convolve A and B
void *process(void *thread_arg) {
  thread_data *args = (thread_data *)thread_arg;
  double *A = args->A;
  double *B = args->B;
  double *C = args->C;
  const mwSize *A_dims = args->A_dims;
  const mwSize *B_dims = args->B_dims;
  const mwSize *C_dims = args->C_dims;
  int num_features = args->A_dims[2];

  for (int f = 0; f < num_features; f++) {
    double *dst = C;
    double *A_src = A + f*A_dims[0]*A_dims[1];      
    double *B_src = B + f*B_dims[0]*B_dims[1];
    for (int x = 0; x < C_dims[1]; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < C_dims[0]; y++) {
    double val = 0;
    for (int xp = 0; xp < B_dims[1]; xp++) {
      double *A_off = A_src + (x+xp)*A_dims[0] + y;
      double *B_off = B_src + xp*B_dims[0];
      switch(B_dims[0]) {
      case 20: val += A_off[19] * B_off[19];
      case 19: val += A_off[18] * B_off[18];
      case 18: val += A_off[17] * B_off[17];
      case 17: val += A_off[16] * B_off[16];
      case 16: val += A_off[15] * B_off[15];
      case 15: val += A_off[14] * B_off[14];
      case 14: val += A_off[13] * B_off[13];
      case 13: val += A_off[12] * B_off[12];
      case 12: val += A_off[11] * B_off[11];
      case 11: val += A_off[10] * B_off[10];
      case 10: val += A_off[9] * B_off[9];
      case 9: val += A_off[8] * B_off[8];
      case 8: val += A_off[7] * B_off[7];
      case 7: val += A_off[6] * B_off[6];
      case 6: val += A_off[5] * B_off[5];
      case 5: val += A_off[4] * B_off[4];
      case 4: val += A_off[3] * B_off[3];
      case 3: val += A_off[2] * B_off[2];
      case 2: val += A_off[1] * B_off[1];
      case 1: val += A_off[0] * B_off[0];
        break;
      default:                
        for (int yp = 0; yp < B_dims[0]; yp++) {
          val += *(A_off++) * *(B_off++);
        }
      }
    }
    *(dst++) += val;
      }
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}

// matlab entry point
// C = fconv(A, cell of B, start, end);
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) { 
  if (nrhs != 4)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of inputs"); 
  if (nlhs != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of outputs");

  // get A
  const mxArray *mxA = prhs[0];
  if (mxGetNumberOfDimensions(mxA) != 3 || 
      mxGetClassID(mxA) != mxDOUBLE_CLASS)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid input: A");

  // get B and start/end
  const mxArray *cellB = prhs[1];
  mwSize num_bs = mxGetNumberOfElements(cellB);  
  int start = (int)mxGetScalar(prhs[2]) - 1;
  int end = (int)mxGetScalar(prhs[3]) - 1;
  if (start < 0 || end >= num_bs || start > end)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid input: start/end");
  int len = end-start+1;

  // output cell
  plhs[0] = mxCreateCellMatrix(1, len);

  // do convolutions
  thread_data td;
  const mwSize *A_dims = mxGetDimensions(mxA);
  double *A = (double *)mxGetPr(mxA);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const mxArray *mxB = mxGetCell(cellB, i+start);
    td.A_dims = A_dims;
    td.A = A;
    td.B_dims = mxGetDimensions(mxB);
    td.B = (double *)mxGetPr(mxB);
    if (mxGetNumberOfDimensions(mxB) != 3 ||
        mxGetClassID(mxB) != mxDOUBLE_CLASS ||
        td.A_dims[2] != td.B_dims[2])
      mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid input: B");

    // compute size of output
    int height = td.A_dims[0] - td.B_dims[0] + 1;
    int width = td.A_dims[1] - td.B_dims[1] + 1;
    if (height < 1 || width < 1)
      mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid input: B should be smaller than A");
    td.C_dims[0] = height;
    td.C_dims[1] = width;
    td.mxC = mxCreateNumericArray(2, td.C_dims, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    td.C = (double *)mxGetPr(td.mxC);
    process((void *)&td);
    mxSetCell(plhs[0], i, td.mxC);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `mex -setup`?

Comment: Also try running the above command with verbosity enabled: `mex -v -setup` so that you can see what may be missing for the SDK that you have installed.  You may want to indicate which version of MATLAB you are using, and what your operating system is (presumably Windows, but which version and whether it is 32- or 64-bit).

Comment: just like this ? is there any other parameters that I need to provide?

Comment: I'm running on windows 7 64bit OS.

Comment: Note that with newer versions of MATLAB (at least R2014b), running `mex -setup` is no longer necessary unless you want to switch compilers and specify your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compile a mex function using the `mex` command, you first need to ensure the following:

1. You have a c/c++ compiler installed
2. You have told Matlab about it using the `mex -setup` command.

In more detail:

1.You have a c/c++ compiler installed:

Matlab provides a 32-bit compiler which is sufficient if you are using 32-bit Matlab, otherwise if you are using 64-bit Matlab you will need to provide a 64-bit compiler.

2.You have told Matlab about it using the `mex -setup` command:

Executing this command will walk you through a wizard which identifies the installed compilers based on their common install locations. Just select the one you want to use.